# WordPress: get author info from post id

Tags: php, wordpress

Or even the author id from the post id. I am trying to return the author meta (author page link and avatar) in the sidebar of a single post page (outside of the post loop). What is the best way to do this? I am using a custom function (see below) to return the post id, but am not sure what function to call next.

```
function this_post_id() {
  global $wp_query;
  $thePostID = $wp_query->post->ID;
  return $thePostID;
}
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
<?php $author_id=$post->post_author; ?>
<img src="<?php the_author_meta( 'avatar' , $author_id ); ?> " width="140" height="140" class="avatar" alt="<?php echo the_author_meta( 'display_name' , $author_id ); ?>" />
<?php the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' , $author_id ); ?>
```

Comment: cool - I'll remove my answer as it's misleading.  Glad you sorted it

Comment: For the record, using echo the_author_meta is superfluous, as the_author_meta already echos the value as it is.

Comment: Note: you must use `global $post` before the `$author_id` var for this to work.

Comment: If you want to retrieve the author meta data without echoing it immmediately, use get_the_author_meta( field, id );
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta

Comment: get_avatar_url($author_id) is a better way to get the url to the author's avatar image.

Answer (score 50):

If you want it outside of loop then use the below code.

```
<?php
$author_id = get_post_field ('post_author', $post_id);
$display_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' , $author_id ); 
echo $display_name;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
**use this code for display Auth Name**

<?php
$auth_id = $post->post_author; 
echo get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $auth_id ); 
?>
```

Comment: While this answer is factually OK, it would be more helpful if you provide an explanation, and supporting evidence

Answer (score 2):

This should work

- Post ID

```
$post_id =  get_the_ID();
$author_id = get_post_field ('post_author', $post_id);
$display_name = get_the_author_meta( 'nickname' , $author_id ); 
echo $display_name;
```

Note: You need to use this function inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php
  $field = 'display_name';
  the_author_meta($field);
?>
```

Valid values for the `$field` parameter include:

- admin_color
- aim
- comment_shortcuts
- description
- display_name
- first_name
- ID
- jabber
- last_name
- nickname
- plugins_last_view
- plugins_per_page
- rich_editing
- syntax_highlighting
- user_activation_key
- user_description
- user_email
- user_firstname
- user_lastname
- user_level
- user_login
- user_nicename
- user_pass
- user_registered
- user_status
- user_url
- yim