# Getting Post Author in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm building a Wordpress template from an HTML page.

I currently have

```
<?php $queried_post = get_post( $_GET['id'], $output ); ?>
```

Then I use ...

```
<?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?>
```

Which works fine for echoing the post title.

Then I try to echo the author with...

```
<?php echo $queried_post->post_author; ?>
```

I get back '1' which is not the author name. How is this done correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php the_author($_GET['id']); ?>
```

Codex entry: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author

---

My `single.php` file:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()): ?>
  <?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post post-single">
      <h1 class="post-title">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '', ''); ?>
      </h1>

      <div class="content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; else: ?>
  There are no posts to display.
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Why are you using `$_GET`? Wordpress handles all of that stuff quite well and has templates for everything. If you're trying to display a single post, try making a `single.php` file and Wordpress will handle all the rest. I've attached my code for that file above.

Comment: But if you insist on your current syntax, look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188901/wordpress-get-author-info-from-post-id