# Wordpress Author Page to allow Commentators as well

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress has an author page that can be used to display posts specific to the current author.
Thus the following functions worth.

```
<?php the_author_meta( 'display_name'); ?>
```

Since anyone who is a user has a page at the `URL/authors` I wanted to display comments of the relevant cementers on their page. I have already built the relevant code to do this but the problem is that no comments will be displayed without knowing the ID of the commentator. This `<?php the_author_meta( 'id'); ?>` does not give the author id because the authors page does not recognise a commentator as an author, I think that is the reason why anyway.

The URL is for example `www.example.com/authors/author_nicename` . How would we get the user_id from the URL or is there another way of getting it.

Answer (score -1):

if the user is logged in, you can get that users ID by using the following:

```
<?php 

  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();

  $user_ID = $current_user->ID;

?>
```

Comment: I did not state that the user was logged in. I thank you for your help but that is not an answer to the question

Comment: I guess I am confused about what you are trying to do then.  You are trying to get the id of an unknown user?  Or are you trying to get the id of the author of the page that is being accessed?

Comment: The author of the id of the page being accessed. I have used a ? variable for now

Comment: In that case, wouldn't this be similar to this topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188901/wordpress-get-author-info-from-post-id

Comment: No not at all. You do not have a post ID. You have only the URL to the author page. This page does exist for any user

Comment: Still a bit unsure of what you are trying to do exactly but I think this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates

And specifically:
     <?php 
       $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) :  get_userdata(intval($author));
     ?>