# Get the author's username using PHP in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, user-data, author, usermetadata

I need to call in the username of a post's author.

I have tried [WordPress: get author info from post id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188901/wordpress-get-author-info-from-post-id/71728473#71728473) answer code.

I have added the code in the post loop, echoing `$display_name`.

It works, but not for what I need, as it displays the nickname.

So I tried changing the 'nickname' to 'username' like:

```
$post_id =  get_the_ID();
$author_id = get_post_field ('post_author', $post_id);
$display_name = get_the_author_meta( 'username' , $author_id );
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field key for the username in WordPress is `user_login`… You could also use the display name which field key is `display_name`.

To get the author username (or display name) try the following instead:

```php
$author_id = get_post_field ('post_author', get_the_ID()); 

if ( $author_id > 0 ) {
    $author = get_userdata( $author_id );
    $user_name    = $author->user_login;
    $display_name = $author->display_name;
}
```